# What is the meaning of multiple class methods separated by "::"?

Tags: c++

I found this line of code where I'm working, but I don't quite understand its meaning:

```
virtual method1::method2::method3 f() = 0;
```

In the `main` function, I have `method1::method2::method3.g1().g2()`. I really don't understand. I know `method::A` where `A` is a class.

Comment: You probably should use a good book for learning c++. Those are namespaces and not methods.

Comment: `::` is a scope resolution operator that checks the right hand operand in the scope of left hand operand.

Comment: If `X::Y::Z` is valid, either `X` is a namespace, or `Y` is a *member class* or *member type* alias of class `X`.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing how `method1`, `method2`, and `method3` are defined. Despite the names given here, they are definitely not member functions (sometimes inaccurately referred to as "methods").

Answer (score 1):

`::` is a scope operator.

You may need to append multiple of them either when using nested classes (a class defined within another class) or when you use *namespaces*. Resolution is done the same way.

Comment: A third possibility: `class X { public: static int n; }; class Y { public: using Z = X; };` and then `Y::Z::n` is a valid name.

Answer (score 0):

**::** is the scope resolution operator. It allows you to statically traverse scopes such as namespaces and classes in order to reference the identifier you want.

I think what you have is not methods but namespaces and classes.